# multi-threading support in soil for opengl

Tags: c++, multithreading, opengl, thread-safety, soil

My question is, is SOIL (simple opengl image library) thread compatible?

Because when I run the following code:

```
Texture = SOIL_load_OGL_texture (
                 loc.c_str(),
                 SOIL_LOAD_AUTO,
                 SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID,
                 SOIL_FLAG_POWER_OF_TWO
                 | SOIL_FLAG_MIPMAPS
                 | SOIL_FLAG_MULTIPLY_ALPHA
                 | SOIL_FLAG_COMPRESS_TO_DXT
                 | SOIL_FLAG_DDS_LOAD_DIRECT
                 | SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y
             );
```

(in order to load a texture)

outside of a thread it works fine, however when run inside an std::thread it gives me the error

> Unhandled exception at 0x592527FF (msvcr110d.dll) in Project2.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

I want to be able to thread it so that it can load during a menu screen, or a splash screen or something of the sort. So my question is if SOIL is not thread safe then would a decent solution be to run a thread to run the menu/ splash screen/ whatever in order to allow textures to load in the main thread?

Comment: It is not so much whether SOIL is thread safe, as it is whether you have a valid OpenGL context in your worker thread. Window systems only allow an OpenGL render context to be bound to a single thread at any given moment, this is worked around by either relinquishing a single context and passing it between threads (synch. overhead makes this a bad idea) or using multiple contexts that share resources. In any event, if you try to use the results of an OpenGL command in a thread that has no OpenGL context bound, this sort of thing tends to happen.

Comment: My bet is that you (or someone else) didn't compile SOIL correctly to use in a multi-threaded program.

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL isTHREAD BOUND!Which means you can make calls on your GL context from a single thread at a time.(Thanks to datenwolf for correction)If the above mentioned method uses GL methods ,which I suppose it does, then it won't work unless you do it in separate GL context.If you want to go multi -threaded way,you can create shared context - each in separate thread.Then you render in the main thread while loading the textures in another one.I am not sure how much it is performance wise,but you can give it a try anyway.

Comment: OpenGL is not really *single threaded*, it's *thread bound*. I.e. at any moment a given OpenGL context can be used from only one thread. It's however possible to migrate a context between threads. And it's possible to access buffer object mappings from all threads of a process.